# ¿Como indicar un orden ascendente o decente?

Tags: c, dev-c++

tenia una duda la cual era la siguiente: ¿Como se podria indicar, en el siguiente programa (abajo lo dejo). Si el orden es de forma ascendente o decendente con tan solo modificar la funcion "sost" y hacer que reciba un tercer parametro, para que realize esta indicacion de si es ascendente o decente?.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(const char **p, const char **i)
{
      const char *temp = *p;
      *p = *i;
      *i = temp;
}

void sost (const char *p[], int size)
{   
for (int k = 0; k<size-1; k++)
{
for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
{
if (i<size-1 && p[i][0] > p[i+1][0]){
    swap(&p[i], &p[i+1]);
 }
}
}
}

int main()
{
const char *p[5];
p[0] = "Barrientos";
p[1] = "Aguirez";
p[2] = "Carmen";
p[3] = "Lopez";
p[4] = "Gomez";

for (int i = 0; i<sizeof p/sizeof(char*); i++)
{
 for (int s= 0 ; p[i][s] !='\0'; s++)
 {
    printf("%c", p[i][s]);
 }
printf("\n");  
}   

sost(p, sizeof p/sizeof(char*));

for (int i = 0; i<sizeof p/sizeof(char*); i++)
 {
 for (int s = 0; p[i][s] != '\0'; s++){
    printf("%c", p[i][s]);
 }
 printf("\n\n");  
 }
}
```